# Why does Magento_Cookie refresh page as default behaviour?

Tags: magento2, cookie

This is very ugly behaviour that I want to change, I am wondering if there is any necessity in the action so I can decide to customise it or rewrite the whole thing.

**Magento/Cookie/view/frontend/web/js/notices.js**

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "mage/cookies"
], function($){
    "use strict";

    $.widget('mage.cookieNotices', {
        _create: function() {
            if ($.mage.cookies.get(this.options.cookieName)) {
                this.element.hide();
            } else {
                this.element.show();
            }
            $(this.options.cookieAllowButtonSelector).on('click', $.proxy(function() {
                var cookieExpires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + this.options.cookieLifetime * 1000);

                $.mage.cookies.set(this.options.cookieName, this.options.cookieValue, {expires: cookieExpires});
                if ($.mage.cookies.get(this.options.cookieName)) {
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    window.location.href = this.options.noCookiesUrl;
                }
            }, this));
        }
    });

    return $.mage.cookieNotices;
});
```

Comment: What is issue you are facing?

Comment: It refreshes the page. I don't like it.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can override `vendor/magento/module-cookie/view/frontend/web/js/notices.js` in your theme :
`app/design/frontend/<YourVendorName>/<yourTheme>/Magento_Cookie/web/js/notices.js`

You can now change it and test :

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "mage/cookies"
], function($){
    "use strict";

    $.widget('mage.cookieNotices', {
        _create: function() {
            var _self = this;
            if ($.mage.cookies.get(this.options.cookieName)) {
                this.element.hide();
            } else {
                this.element.show();
            }
            $(this.options.cookieAllowButtonSelector).on('click', $.proxy(function() {
                var cookieExpires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + this.options.cookieLifetime * 1000);

                $.mage.cookies.set(this.options.cookieName, this.options.cookieValue, {expires: cookieExpires});

                if ($.mage.cookies.get(this.options.cookieName)) {
                    _self.element.hide();
                } else {
                    window.location.href = this.options.noCookiesUrl;
                }
            }, this));
        }
    });

    return $.mage.cookieNotices;
});
```